# Rendering a scale meter on Google Maps Static

Tags: google-maps

Is it possible to put some sort of scale meter (denoting distance representation) on top of a [Google Static Map](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/)?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem feasible with the static maps api, but maybe you could put an image with the scale meter and position it with css on top of the map image.

Comment: The issue is, how do you know what scale to size the CSS meter?

Comment: reading the static map api documentation, seems a bit difficult.. there is a scale parameter, but I think you should refer to [http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/overlays.html#Google_Maps_Coordinates] as there explains the relation between zoom levels and tiles, which I guess, could be extrapolated to earth distance to compute scale. Sorry not to be able to help further at the moment.